# Jenkins Script: Trigger using Shell not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

I am using Jenkins script polling.

- [ScriptTrigger] - Poll with a shell or batch script IS CHECKED
- script value is

  ```
  #!/bin/ksh
  return 0
  ```
- Exit Code PARAMETER IS 0
- polling   Schedule is `* * * * *`

The polling is never happening and the build run only if i schedule a build manually .

What am i doing wrong? What should i change?

The script trigger log is

> [ScriptTrigger] - Poll with a shell or batch script
>
> Polling has not run yet.

Comment: Please don't [scream](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44296771/revisions).

Comment: @StephenKing in such a situation :) . . in big trouble at job because of this

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @gregory-boissinot please help

Comment: i couldn't get it work but used 2 Jenkins job . one job i am using for polling and the other i am using for triggering jobs . made the trigger job to execute on the success of the polling job . This works fine for my requirement where jenkins is polling for a condition via a shell and jenkins is doing an action as a response